# Highlight Blog menu when single post is viewed

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to highlight the main blog roll when viewing a single post. There is only one category for posts and there is no menu showing this category so I cannot use .current-post-ancestor.

I have the following function, but I am getting errors I do not understand. The category is "show" and the id of the Blog page is 15

```
//Highlight Blog Link in main menu when on post page
function post_css_class( $css_class, $page ) {

if (in_category('show') == $page->15 ) {
    $css_class[] = '#header .menu .current_page_item a';
}
return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'page_css_class', 'post_css_class', 10, 2 );`
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe we can understand the errors...

Comment: I'm sure you can, I wish I could...

Comment: Lynne, what @koala_dev implied is "add the errors to your Question". Also, you are providing valuable information in the Comments to Alexander's Answer. Please, go improving the Q as new feedback arrives.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if( is_single() && in_category('show') && $page->ID == 15 ) {
        $classes[] = 'current_page_item';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

might work?

Anyhow, you're not supposed to use page_css_class, look at this instead for reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class

Comment: Nope it didn't work. My logic was wrong, I think I need to tell it to highlight the menu-item-id-19 as current_page_item, if the page is single and the category is 'show'

Comment: oops couldn't get my new code to show                            function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if( is_single() && in_category('show')) {
        $classes[] = '#header .menu .current-menu-item-19 a';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );

Comment: The code was correct, but still not highlighting the Blog link...??? Any ideas anyone, I have looked all over for this?

Comment: I have changed the php to the following, but still not working although there are no errors.                                            `function blog_link_genesis() {
 if( is_single() && in_category('show')) { 
 $current = '#header .menu .current-menu-item #menu-item-19 a';  }
 ?>

 <style type="text/css">
 <?php echo $current; ?> { color: #ef4634;}
 </style>
 <?php }

add_action( 'genesis_header' , 'blog_link_genesis'  );`

Comment: You're adding a css path to $classes, it's not the same thing as a class name.. Why is my code above not working? Could you check the html to see how things render? Maybe change the 15 to 19?

Answer (score 0):

Got it - Yay - so if anyone else is looking for the same thing here is my function:

```
function blog_link_genesis() {
if( is_single() && in_category('show')) { 
$current = '#header .menu #menu-item-19 a';  }
?>
<style type="text/css">
<?php echo $current; ?> { color: #ef4634;}
</style>
<?php }
add_action( 'genesis_header' , 'blog_link_genesis'  );
```

and this is the CSS I added

## header .menu .current-menu-item #menu-item-19 a{color: #ef4634;}

I probably have superfluous markup in there, if anyone wishes to correct it, be my guest!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
<?php if (is_single() || is_category() || is_tag() || is_search()) {   //  displaying a single blog post or a blog archive ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery("li.current_page_parent").addClass('current-menu-item');
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

How it works is that the code checks if the page the user is on is either a single post or an archive (category, tag or search).

If true, the navigation menu item `li` tag with the class `current_page_parent` (in your case is the “Blog” link) gets assigned another native WordPress navigation menu `li` class `current-menu-item` making the link display as active or highlighted, depends on how it was styled.

If you need more details on this, I write a short piece explaining the process here: [Keep “Blog” link highlighted when viewing a single post](http://bibiano.io/highlight-blog-link/)